# Batch copy folders to variable destination based on second underscore delimited part in folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First of all, I don't have really much experience writing batch scripts. With help from this and other sites I wrote some scripts copying files from several PCs which are not connected to the network to a USB drive. Now I want to copy these backup-folder to a NAS drive. The backup folders are all named like:

```
backup_PC1_data1_dd-mm-yyyy
backup_PC1_data2_dd-mm-yyyy
backup_PC2_data1_dd-mm-yyyy
backup_PC2_data2_dd-mm-yyyy
...
```

The NAS drive `G:\` contains the folders:

```
 ABC_PC1
 ABC_PC2
 ...
```

Now I want to copy the folders from the USB drive to the NAS drive according to the folder names.

For example: `Backup_PC1_data1_tt-mm-yyyy` and `Backup_PC1_data2_tt-mm-yyyy` should be copied to the folder `ABC_PC1` on the NAS drive, `Backup_PC2_data1_tt-mm-yyyy` and `Backup_PC2_data2_tt-mm-yyyy` should be copied to the folder `ABC_PC2` on the NAS drive.

Since the USB to NAS copy process should work on different PCs and some PCs have more than one HDD I want to start the `copy2NAS` script from the USB drive. I started with getting the drive letter and set the source drive with:

```
set drive=%~d0
set source=%drive%
```

My plan was to get all folders in source named `Backup_*` with:

```
for /d %%i in ("%source%\Backup_*")
```

and then something like splitting the name of the source folder and using the part between `Backup_` and `_data…` to define the destination folder (always `G:\ABC_XXX`) where `XXX` is the part between `Backup_` and `_data*` of the source folder name.

Writing a code like:

- For all folders on the USB drive check if name is `Backup_*`.
- If yes split name and extract the part between `Backup_` and `_data*`.
- Use the extracted part of the source folder name to specify the destination folder.
- Copy source folder (and the files in it) to destination.

I have coded so far:

```
set drive=%~d0
set source=%drive%
for /d %%i in (%source%\Backup_*) do call :ProcessDir "%%i"

:ProcessDir
set "foldername=%~n1"
echo %foldername%
for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("%foldername%") do set nthstring=%%a
set "Source=%source%\%foldername%"
set "destination=C:\mol\backups\backup_nas\GMH_%nthstring%\%foldername%"
robocopy %Source% %destination% /s
```

But it looks like this is beyond my batch scripting skills. I either ended up with no copy process, or just the files to a newly created destination, or ...

I almost forgot to mention that the `Backup_*` folders are not the only folders on the USB drive.

Has anybody an idea how to realize this task?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and explain what you have trouble with! What should happen in case a file is already present in the destination directory?

Comment: instead of `for /d`you shouild use `for /f "tokens=1-4delims=_" %%A in ('Dir /B/AD backup_*_*_* ^|findstr "[0-9][0-9]*-[0-9][0-9]*-20[0-9][0-9]$" ') Do Echo # %%A # %%B # %%C # %%D #` The echo only for demonstration.

Comment: So far I have this:

`set drive=%~d0
set source=%drive%

for /d %%i in (%source%\Backup_*) do call :ProcessDir "%%i"
:ProcessDir
set "foldername=%~n1"
echo % foldername %
for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("%foldername %") do set nthstring=%%a
set "Source=%source%\% foldername %"
set "destination=C:\mol\backups\backup_nas\GMH_%nthstring%\% foldername %"
robocopy %Source% % destination % /s`

Comment: @Moe_S do you really have those spaces in `% foldername %`??

Comment: No. I replaced some german words using word. The spaces have been automatically inserted. Sry.

Comment: Don't forget the `exit /b` at the end of your `:ProcessDir` function. It will exit the whole batch script at the end of your first call if you don't add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following batch code:

```
@echo off
for /D %%I in ("%~d0\backup_*_*") do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%J in ("%%~nxI") do (
        echo Copying %%I to G:\ABC_%%J ...
        %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I" "G:\ABC_%%J\%%~nxI\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y /Z >nul
    )
)
```

The outer **FOR** loop finds because of option `/D` (directories) in root directory of drive of the batch file non hidden **directories** with a name starting with `backup_` and having at least one more underscore in directory name.

The loop variable `I` holds on each loop run the found directory name with complete path which is never enclosed in double quotes.

The inner **FOR** gets just the name of the backup directory as string in double quotes referenced with `%%~nxI`. `%%~nI` would be interpreted as the string after last backslash or start of string in case of no backslash up to but not including last point or end of string in case of no point after last backslash/start of string which means the name of a directory or file without extension. `%%~xI` would be interpreted as string from last point after last backslash/start of string to end of string which means the file extension. Therefore `%%~nxI` is the string after last backslash/start of string in parsed string which is either the entire name of a file or directory. Just `%%~nI` would be also enough for directories with no point in directory name like here.

The inner **FOR** parses because of option `/F` and the **string enclosed in double quotes** within first `(`...`)` just this **string**. So it does not search for files, or parses output of a command line, or reads lines from a text file as also possible with using option `/F`. It just parses the string between the two double quotes.

This string being the backup directory name is split up into multiple strings using the underscore character as delimiter specified with `delims=_` instead of spaces/tabs as used by default as delimiters.

It is specified with `tokens=2` that just the second string between 1 or more underscores or end of string is of further interest.

Therefore the inner loop variable `J` holds for the backup directory examples just the string between first and second underscore.

So all needed for copying a backup folder on USB drive to appropriate folder on NAS drive is determined now.

The command **XCOPY** (available also on Windows XP) is used to copy the entire backup folder with all its subfolders and files to the folder on NAS drive which is even automatically created if not existing at all.

It is important to specify as destination folder also the name of the backup folder as otherwise just the files and subfolders of the backup folder would be copied to `G:\ABC_PCx`.

And it is also important to end destination folder with a backslash to let command **XCOPY** know that the destination is a folder and not a file. The option `/I` is not really necessary on specifying the destination with a backslash at end.

It is necessary to use command **DIR** for copying also backup directories with hidden attribute set on backup folder:

```
@echo off
for /F %%I in ('dir /AD /B "%~d0\backup_*_*" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        echo Copying %~d0\%%I to G:\ABC_%%J ...
        %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~d0\%%I" "G:\ABC_%%J\%%I\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y /Z >nul
    )
)
```

The command **DIR** returns because of option `/AD` (attribute directory) just directories matching the pattern `backup_*_*` in root directory of drive of the batch file in bare format because of option `/B` which means just the name of the directory without path and never enclosed in double quotes. The directory can even have the hidden attribute set.

The outer **FOR** runs because of option `/F` and the **string enclosed in single quotes** within first `(`...`)` this string as command line to execute and processes each line output by this command line to handle **STDOUT**.

The inner **FOR** works as explained above whereby it must be taken into account now that the loop variable `I` holds just the backup directory name output by command **DIR** without complete path. Therefore referencing the backup directory name is a little bit different in all 3 commands in command block of outer **FOR**.

`2^>nul` redirects the error message output by command **DIR** on execution by **FOR** to the handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress it. A confusing error message is output by **DIR** if it could not find any backup directory. It is necessary here to escape `>` with `^` to get this character later on execution of **DIR** interpreted as redirection operator and not already as wrong positioned redirection operator on parsing the **FOR** command line. Using just `2>nul` within the command line to execute by **FOR** would result in an exit of batch processing because of a syntax error.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `xcopy /?`

And see also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: I have been on a trip for a few days therefore I'm only replying to you now. Thank you. The code does exactly what I want.